# replace recovery partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

i have a hp laptop with vista on it. i want to format the partition with the recovery files on it and format the c drive, install win7 and create new recovery files for win7 on the second partition.  can someone give me the steps to do this? sorry if this sounded vague but i didn't really know how to say it.

Answer (score 1):

The HP recovery partitions are done by HP with their own software and configurations. But you can do your own, however it would require some software you would need to purchase, if you want to do it right. Here is a guide on using both PartitionMagic and Ghost together to accomplish this.

[PC Magazine Guide](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2014353,00.asp)

Answer (score 1):

HP uses a different solution to prepare recovery partition and assign a preboot key to this. If you format the secondary partition then you would not be able to mount Windows 7 on to it. The best option is to take a backup of your data and then proceed to mount and overwrite the existing image.